# A question on A-orthogonality of two vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, orthonormal, gradient-descent

I am reading [this](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake-papers/painless-conjugate-gradient.pdf) monograph by **Jonathan Richard Shewchuk** on **conjugate gradient descent method**. Call two vector $a$ and $b$ A-orthonomal if $a^TAb=0$, where $A$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix. In page 28-29 a geometric intuition of this is provided without explanation. It says

> Figure 22(a) shows what A-orthogonal vectors look like. Imagine if this article were printed on bubble gum, and you grabbed Figure 22(a) by the ends and stretched it until the ellipses appeared circular. The vectors would then appear orthogonal, as in Figure 22(b).

All this images are in that monograph. I fail to understand this. Can anyone please provide some rigorous explanation for this.

Comment: Length, orthogonality and angles are defined by the inner product (given by $A$). When compared to the standard basis with Euclidean inner product, the resulting geometry looks “warped” in comparison.

Comment: Yes, $<,>_A$ is indeed an inner product. But I just fail to understand the stretching part. Is there some kind of topological argument involved?

Comment: Look at $A = {\rm diag}(1,2)$, for example, to understand amd's comment.

Comment: Not at all. They’re giving a visual description of mapping from an $A$-orthonormal basis to the standard basis with Euclidean inner product.